# comparing two strings using IEnumerable

Tags: vb.net

I want to compare lines between two lines and print them. I have the following code to do this

```
Dim linesA As [String]() = File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text)
Dim linesB As [String]() = File.ReadAllLines(TextBox2.Text)

Dim onlyB As IEnumerable(Of [String]) = linesB.Except(linesA)
```

It does not do the job when there are some extra tabs that occur before the string
How do I eliminate all the tabs and spaces in a line before I compare them?
Thanks

Comment: Could you create your own class that implements IEnumerable and IComparable?  That way your comparison method could deal with the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one line has an leading tab and the other doesnt, they are not equal so the default comparison doesn't work.  However `Except` has an overload which allows you to specify a custom `Equality` comparer where you can provide your own comparison logic:

```
Public Class LineComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String)

    Public Function Equals1(x As String, y As String) As Boolean _
                         Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String).Equals
        Return (String.Compare(x.Trim(), y.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0)
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As String) As Integer _
                              Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String).GetHashCode
        Return obj.Trim().GetHashCode
    End Function
End Class
```

Note that `Except` uses `GetHashCode1` for the comparing.

Usage:

```
Dim justB = linesB.Except(linesA, New LineComparer())
```

The difference between this and Mr Blackwood's answer is that this doesn't change the data loaded for `ListA` or `ListB`.  It simply ignore tabs and spaces when comparing.  It is not clear which one is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Select` extension method to process each of the lines before storing them in `linesA` or `linesB`. For example, if you only want to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace characters, you can use the `Trim` function.

```
Dim linesA As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text).Select(Function(l) l.Trim)
Dim linesB As IEnumerable(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox2.Text).Select(Function(l) l.Trim)

Dim onlyB As IEnumerable(Of String) = linesB.Except(linesA)
```